# How to automatically remove part of the legend that was assigned by default?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have the legend (Species) named by default. Is there any way to delete "wt" - at the end of the words in the legend, automatically? Thank you!

[image: Here is the plot]

Here is the code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)


weedweights<-data%>%
  select(-ends_with("No"))%>%
     gather(key=species, value=speciesmass, DIGSAWt:UnknownmonocotWt)%>%
     mutate(realmass= (10*speciesmass) / samplearea.m.2.)%>%
     group_by(Rot.Herb, species)%>%
     summarize(avgrealmass=mean(realmass, na.rm=TRUE))%>%
     filter(avgrealmass != "NaN")%>%
     ungroup()

ww2 <- weedweights %>%
  group_by(Rot.Herb) %>%
  mutate(totalweedweight=sum(avgrealmass)) %>%
  ungroup()

ggplot(weedweights, aes(x=1, y=avgrealmass, fill=species, order=avgrealmass)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ Rot.Herb) + 
  coord_polar("y") +
  ggtitle("Weedbiomass by crop phase and herbicide regime")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20, face="bold", vjust=2))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank())+
  xlab("Weed dry biomass (kg per ha)")+
  ylab("Crop phase and herbicide regime")
```

And here you can see the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jb6gjznyw2q16mx/AADcNKiicqkoHxpFYIsaTgk9a?dl=0)

Comment: I can't test it, since I don't have your data, but my guess is that `ww2$species <- gsub("wt$", "", ww2$species)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by Zé Loff you can substitute specie variable

```
weedweights <- data%>%
  select(-ends_with("No"))%>%
  gather(key=species, value=speciesmass, DIGSAWt:UnknownmonocotWt)%>%
  mutate(realmass= (10*speciesmass) / samplearea.m.2.)%>%
  group_by(Rot.Herb, species)%>%
  summarize(avgrealmass=mean(realmass, na.rm=TRUE))%>%
  filter(avgrealmass != "NaN")%>%
  ungroup() %>% mutate(species = gsub("Wt$", "", species))
```